# hover effect for block in HTML.ActionLink

Tags: css, razor

I have my navbar looking the way I want but now I want it so the block lights up when a user hovers over it.  I can get the block clickable but not change the color:

Here is my view code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Active Products", "MinimumProductInfoList", "MinimumProductInfo", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand minimum-inventory", Style = "color:White;" })
@Html.ActionLink("Inactive Products", "InactiveProductInfoList", "MinimumProductInfo", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand minimum-inventory", Style = "color:White;" })
```

and here is my css

```
#nav li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 25px 10px;
}

.minimum-inventory li a:hover {
    background-color: #000000
}

#nav a {
    color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here is the outputed html:

```
<div class="navbar-Atalanta navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container col-md-8 col-lg-10 pull-left">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="left">
                    <img src="/Images/AtalantaLogo.png" id="logo" />

                </div>
            </div>
            <a Style="color:White;" class="navbar-brand minimum-inventory" href="/MinimumProductInfo/MinimumProductInfoList">Active Products</a>
            <a Style="color:White;" class="navbar-brand minimum-inventory" href="/MinimumProductInfo/InactiveProductInfoList">Inactive Products</a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" >
```

Comment: How the output html looks like?

Comment: @Dekel the look isn't the problem - the hover effect isn't working.  It is changing the icon to the hand but the background of my block is not changing

Comment: Without looking at the html we can't really know what the css will do

Comment: @Dekel sorry at first I thought you wanted an image of the screen. you want me to do inspect element.  No problem, will do now.

Comment: No, not inspect. Do a "view source", copy the relevant code, and update the question with the relevant code.

Comment: Your `<a>` elements have `class="minimum-inventory"`, and they do no contain `<li>` elements which contain `<a>` elements (which is what `.minimum-inventory li a:hover` means). You selector needs to be just `.minimum-inventory:hover { background-color: #000000 }`

Comment: Note also you should remove `new { Style = "color:White;" }` - you already have that in your css

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thank you the hover is working now.  However, I cannot remove new { Style = "color:White;" } because the text turns blue then.  I even tried adding !important on the coloring in the css.  I cannot figure it out

Comment: You obviously have some other css overriding your `#nav a { color: white;` code - just use you browser tools to inspect the element and its styles to see where the `color: blue` is coming from

Comment: @StephenMuecke I understand that but shouldn't !important override that? plus doesn't it run in order that css code I showed you was the last code in my css file

Comment: Not necessarily - for example you might have a `<style>` tag in your view with styles that takes precedence

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you, I will look for that